# Correct Way to Override Iterables<Obj> in Java

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

this is a code i have written for implementing linked list,

```
private class DequeIterator<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    private Node pElement;

    DequeIterator() {
        pElement = first;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return pElement != null;
    }

    public Item next() {
        if (!this.hasNext()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        Item ret = pElement.it;
        pElement = pElement.next;
        return ret;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

I dont know what is going wrong i am getting follwing errors please help me resolve those

=> Deque.java:25: error: Deque.DequeIterator is not abstract and does not override abstract method iterator() in Iterable

=>Deque.java:35: error: incompatible types
            Item ret = pElement.it;
                               ^
  required: Item#2
  found:    Item#1

=>Deque.java:121: error: incompatible types
        return new DequeIterator();
               ^
  required: Iterator
  found:    Deque.DequeIterator

Comment: You have declared that the class `implements Iterable` and then implemented `Iterator`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are implementing the wrong interface. [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) requires that you implement the `iterator()` method, which you are not providing. Thus the first error.

You probably want to implement [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) instead, which requires `hasNext()`, `next()` and `remove()`.

You didn't show the rest of your code, but I presume you have `Deque.java` which has the rest of the linked list code (i.e. a reference to the `head` etc.), so probably you might want to have `Deque implements Iterable<Item>` with the `iterator()` method returning an instance of `DequeIterator`.

You also need to remove the `<Item>` from the `DequeueIterator`. You are already saying it implements `Iterable<Item>`, so you are restricting the type. You are changing it to a generic type instead, which is the reason for the second error. I presume that `Item` is a concrete class defined somewhere else (especially since `pElement` returns it and does not have a generic type associated with it).

The third error, no idea what's in line 121, you didn't include it. But most probably its for the same reason I mentioned above (`DequeIterator` needs to implement `Iterator` not `Iterable`)

Comment: Oh thanks, your suggestion solved 1st and 3rd errors, please tell me how to resolve 2nd error?

Comment: Just change `DequeIterator<Item>` to `DequeIterator`. You are creating a new generic type when in fact I presume you have a normal concrete class called `Item`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your internal `DequeIterator` class is overriding the `<Item>` generic from the top class `Deque<Item>`. Just remove the `<Item>` from `DequeIterator` definition. Also, the class that should implement `Iterable` must be your `Deque` class, and `DequeIterator` must implement `Iterator`.

```
public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
    //implementation...
    private class DequeIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
        //implementation...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Deque.java:25: error: Deque.DequeIterator is not abstract and does not
>   override abstract method iterator() in Iterable

In class `Iterable` exist method `iterator()`, which is abstract. You are responsible for implementing every abstract method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `iterator()` method in your class `DequeIterator<Item>` as it implements `Iterable` interface.

```
hasNext(), next(), remove() - these methods are in Iterator interface.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Iterator implements Iterable instead of implementing Iterator. Always add the `@Override` annotation on methods which are supposed to override a base class or interface method.